# Add onkeyup="countChar(this)" in textarea form Symfony 5

Tags: symfony

In FormType, I've this

```
->add('message', TextareaType::class, [
      'label' => 'form.input.message',
      'help' => 'form.input.help.message'
])
```

In index.html.twig

```
<div class="form-group">
   {{ form_label(form.message) }}
   <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
       { form_widget(form.message) }}
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I add  onkeyup="countChar(this)" in this textarea?

To get:

```
<textarea id="thanks_message" onkeyup="countChar(this)" name="thanks[message]" class="form-control" required="required"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docs reads to me like you can do so:

```
->add('message', TextareaType::class, [
      'attr' => ['onkeyup' => 'countChar(this)'],
      'label' => 'form.input.message',
      'help' => 'form.input.help.message'
]);
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/textarea.html

alternatively you could just use javascript to handle keyup event on that element